# Red overlay in Silverlight in IE

Tags: silverlight

Having a strange issue with a Silverlight app in IE 9...

The entire Silverlight canvas is rendered in a red overlay. Only in IE. Not in Firefox, not in Chrome... And no; there isn't a layer above it defined in Xaml ;)

Screenshot: (left: IE / right: Chrome)

[image]

([larger image here](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0acpkx9ec))

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Could it be the EnableRedrawRegions property set to true? Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.settings.enableredrawregions(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the EnableCacheVisualization is set to true.

check out in your web Project, in the [YourApp].aspx (or also [YourApp.html]) file markup if you see something like :

```
<param name="EnableCacheVisualization" value="true" />
```

or it may be set somewhere else in your project code :

```
App.Current.Host.Settings.EnableCacheVisualization = true;
```